# Readonly text field in Flask-Admin ModelView

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

How can I make a field on a `ModelView` readonly?

```
class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_list = ('name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're talking about Flask-Admin with SQLAlchemy Models, and you're declaring a view by inheriting from sqlamodel.ModelView, you can just add this to your class definition:

```
class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_list = ('name', 'last_name', 'email')
    form_widget_args = {
        'email':{
            'disabled':True
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might not be what you want. I implemented this but noticed that the fields that were disabled were getting **cleared** on submission. When I used `readonly` instead, then I got the expected behavior (value doesn't change).

Answer (score 11):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on @thkang's answer, which is very close to what worked for me. The `disabled` attribute excludes the field from the POST data, but using `readonly` had the desired effect.

```
from wtforms.fields import TextField

class ReadonlyTextField(TextField):
  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('readonly', True)
    return super(ReadonlyTextField, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is there any way to set it vai the follow?   form_widget_args = {
        'type_values': {
            'readonly': 'readonly'
        }
    }

Comment: Lawrence, I would specify form_extra_fields as the same name as the field you want to be readOnly and it will override this field.

Comment: i.e. form_overrides = dict(your_field_name=ReadonlyTextField) or possibly form_extra_fields = dict(your_field_name=ReadonlyTextField('Label',...))

Answer (score 8):

I got weird errors when I tried to use `disabled` for text fields, so I used `readonly` instead:

```
class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_list = ('name', 'last_name', 'email')
    form_widget_args = {
        'email':{
            'readonly':True
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
class DisabledTextField(TextField):
  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('disabled', True)
    return super(DisabledTextField, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6):

When you are rendering the field in your Jinja template, just pass in `disabled=true` if WTForms doesn't recognise the kwarg, it just passes it to be an attribute to the html element.

```
<form>
{{ form.example(disabled=True) }}
</form>
```