# Python Flask WTForms: How can I disable a field dynamically in a view?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I've been able to implement [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874846/python-flask-wtforms-make-read-only-textfield) to create Field which is disabled in WTForms.  How would I selectively disable a field in my view before rendering it?

Comment: You could try `form.field(disabled_="disabled")` in template. http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__

Answer (score 26):

vim forms.py:

```
add_time = DateTimeField(

    '添加时间',
    format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    default=datetime.datetime.now(),
    # I use bs3，and it well add input an attribute disabled
    render_kw={'disabled':''},
    validators=[DataRequired()],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case, the form had already been instantiated, so I just did `form.my_field.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled'}`.

Comment: @elethan consider posting that as an answer so the questioner can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 11):

It's almost as @Bibhas proposed. 
If I understand this correctly and you want to disable a field through the html disabled attribute, then the following worked for me:

```
form.field(disabled=True)
```

This answer might be a bit late, but if any one else has this problem it might help.

Comment: this would be at render time - what if we want to do it at definition time?

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to remove a field you could look at the [Removing Fields Per-instance](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/specific_problems.html#removing-fields-per-instance) in the documentation.

From the docs:

> Sometimes, you create a form which has fields that aren’t useful in
>   all circumstances or to all users. While it is indeed possible with
>   form inheritance to define a form with exactly the fields you need,
>   sometimes it is necessary to just tweak an existing form. Luckily,
>   forms can have fields removed post-instantiation by using the del
>   keyword:

```
class MagazineIssueForm(Form):
    title  = TextField()
    year   = IntegerField('Year')
    month  = SelectField(choices=MONTHS)

def edit_issue():
    publication = get_something_from_db()
    form = MagazineIssueForm(...)

    if publication.frequency == 'annual':
        del form.month`
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm looking to disable the field, not delete it.

Comment: Ah sorry - I misunderstood. How do you mean disable? Display it but make it so the field can't be modified?

Comment: This is very similar to another question, and I wrote a detailed answer there as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16576294/244393

Answer (score 1):

I am using helper functions below.
**Example usage**

```py
 for button in [ttForm.instancesButton,ttForm.propertiesButton,ttForm.idButton,ttForm.labelButton,ttForm.clearButton]:
            self.setInputDisabled(button)
        self.enableButtonsOnInput([ttForm.idButton,ttForm.clearButton],ttForm.itemLabel)
        self.enableButtonsOnInput([ttForm.labelButton,ttForm.clearButton,ttForm.instancesButton], ttForm.itemId)
        self.enableButtonsOnInput([ttForm.propertiesButton], ttForm.itemCount)
```

**helper functions**

```py
  def setInputDisabled(self,inputField,disabled:bool=True):
        '''
        disable the given input
        
        Args:
            inputField(Input): the WTForms input to disable
            disabled(bool): if true set the disabled attribute of the input 
        '''
        if inputField.render_kw is None:
            inputField.render_kw={}
        if disabled:
            inputField.render_kw["disabled"]= "disabled"
        else:
            inputField.render_kw.pop("disabled")
            
    def setRenderKw(self,inputField,key,value):
        '''
        set a render keyword dict entry for the given input field with the given key and value
        
        Args:
            inputField(Input): the field to modify
            key(str): the key to use
            value(str): the value to set
        '''
        if inputField.render_kw is None:
            inputField.render_kw={}
        inputField.render_kw[key]=value
        
    def enableButtonsOnInput(self,buttons:list,inputField):
        '''
        enable the given list of buttons on input in the given inputField
        
        Args:
            inputField(Input): the inputField to set the input trigger
            buttons(list): the list of buttons to enable
        '''
        script=""
        for button in buttons:
            script+=f"document.getElementById('{button.id}').disabled = false;"
        self.setRenderKw(inputField,"oninput",script)
```