# how to disable submit button of wtform submit field?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

this is a submit button code of a wtform:

```
{{ form.submit(class="w-50 btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-btn") }}
```

I am thinking of adding a class to it when it's clicked? i know a way of showing errors in wtform+jinja2 by adding class like this:

```
{% if reg_form.confirm_password.errors %}
   {{ reg_form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
             {% for error in reg_form.confirm_password.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
             {% endfor %}
          </div>
   {% else %}
       {{ reg_form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
   {% endif %}
```

i looked at the docs of submitField but I cannot see a way of disabling it. https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask WTForms: How can I disable a field dynamically in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424374/python-flask-wtforms-how-can-i-disable-a-field-dynamically-in-a-view)

Comment: Do you want to disable before clicking or after clicking?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly during the definition of your form as:

```py
# forms.py

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    # ...
    submit = SubmitField("Submit", render_kw={"disabled": "disabled"})

# Then simply render your form
# index.html

{{ form.submit() }}
```

Or, you can do it from the templates as:

```html
<!-- index.html -->


{{ form.submit.render_kw={"disabled": "disabled"} }}

<!-- OR -->

{{ form.submit(disabled=True) }}
```