# Readonly form field in edit view - Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I tried to set a form field as `readonly` just for the *edit* view in a Flask-Admin application. Following the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14874846/2371501) question I know that if I have this

```
class MyView(ModelView):
    form_widget_args = {
        'title': {
            'readonly': True
        }
    }
```

I can set a form field as `readonly`, but this is applied to both *create* and *edit* views. How can I apply an argument to the *edit* view only?

Answer (score 15):

A pure python solution could be using the `on_form_prefill` callback function that admin provides, and it's only run in the edit view. You wouldn't need `form_widget_args` in that case.

You could have something like this to edit the form dynamically, making that field read only:

```
class MyView(ModelView):
  def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
    form.title.render_kw = {'readonly': True}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is to use [form_edit_rules](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_create_rules) and [form_create_rules](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_create_rules). Display the fields you only want in create view, and add the field you want to be displayed in edit view and make it read-only

```
form_create_rules = (
    'col1', 'col2', 'col3')
form_edit_rules = (
    'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')

form_widget_args = {
    'col4': {
        'disabled': True
    }
}
```

Comment: can col4 be included in create rules? read only only in edit mode

Answer (score 3):

I would do a little workaround for this. Create a [custom edit template](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.edit_template) and add it to your class. The standard edit template you find in the flask repository on github [(standard edit template)](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap2/admin/model/edit.html)

```
class MyView(ModelView):
    edit_template = 'my_custom_edit_template.html'
```

And in your custom edit template make a javascript function which disables your element. So it's only disabled in edit view and not in the create view.

```
{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ lib.form_js() }}
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("myfield_id").disabled = true;
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

It's maybe not the best solution but it works for me. I think it should also be possible to change the jinja2 template to directly disable the filed. I tried: {{ form.myfield_id(disabled=True) }}  but then it renders my field twice... but my first approach works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by checking the value you are trying to edit in the method that handles edit.
For eg:
You are trying to edit a value with id 1, then in the views py file you can check for the that value and add the code.

```
def editdata(id=None):
    if id:
        form.title.render_kw = {'readonly': True}
#rest of the code
```